# How to retrieve a the return value of a shell function execute with `` and $()

Tags: linux, shell, ash

I have the following function:

```
func() {
   echo any
   return 3;
}
```

when I execute this funtion in the following ways, and then I display the returned value of the function with `echo $?` I got 0 and not 3:

```
Linux# x=`func`
Linux# echo $?
0
Linux# x=`eval func`
Linux# echo $?
0
Linux# x=$(eval func)
Linux# echo $?
0
```

How I can got the returned value of func in the above cases?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Getting 3 in `bash`, `sh` and `ash`.

Comment: Do you have something in your prompt command which messes up the return code?  In that case, `x=$(func); echo $?` on a single command line should display the correct, expected outcome.

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic / not reproducable. (The question "what is wrong with the OP's shell" is a completely different one...)